# Laravel Sanctum return: Call to a member function createToken() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

I am following sanctum documentation from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens).  I did all same as described but still it is not working.
I am getting an error when I am generating new token "Call to a member function createToken() on null".

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('/tokens/create', function (Request $request) {
    $token = $request->user()->createToken($request->token_name);
 
    return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
});
```

Here is my code on github https://github.com/farukhaleem/sanctum

I am trying to use sanctum as it is described in the documentation. I am getting createToken() method for generating a token but I am unable to get anyting in $request->user(). I am using thunder client in vscode for getting result. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tokens/create is the endpoint, method type is POST. FORM data has token_name with value 'data'

Comment: what is the use case? are trying to log the user in?

Comment: I am new and I am learning how to use Sanctum. I just follow the documentation and expected to generate the token in this step https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation assumes you have an authenticated user in your case you don't. this is why `$request->user()` is null.

So in order to just generate a token you could use the following

```
Route::post('/tokens/create', function (Request $request) {

    $user = User::find("some user id");
    $token = $user->createToken($request->token_name);
 
    return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
});
```

Since you are learning, it would make more sense if you transform your route into a log in with a form where the users can enter their email and password so on submit you generate the token.

```
Route::post('/login', function (Request $request) {

    # do any validations here

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    $token = $user->createToken("The user agent here");
 
    return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
});
```

Also note that on `createToken` it would be better if you pass the user agent. so you know the app that uses that specific token.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I did not seed the user, which is why I could not create a token.

Now, I seed the first user data, and I am authenticating that user in the login route. 

And now it is working fine as I expected.